# javascript optimization to avoid function context

Tags: javascript, performance

I have the following code (trucated for clarity):

```
if ( typeof CPM == "undefined" || !CPM) {var CPM={};}

(function(){
  CPM.process = {
    createStyles: function() {
      //Do style processing
      alert("processing styles");
    },
    createClasses = {
      //Do style processing
      alert("processing classes");      
    },
    init: function(){CPM.process.createStyles()}
  };
})();
```

init is a convention used in the company and must be there for other reasons. What I am trying to avoid is an additional function call for init. Is there an alternative way to write the same init and avoid creation of the function context? Like:

```
init: CPM.process.createStyles
```

The above fails, but am trying to see if there is any other way of achieving the optimization

Comment: I think you meant, "What I am trying to avoid is ..." but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: That fails only because you didn't define it yet when creating the object literal. Or do you talk of the `this` context?

Comment: @Pointy, you are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `init: CPM.process.createStyles` directly fails because `CPM.process` isn't defined yet at the point of the `init` key assignment. You need to build your object in two steps:

```
  CPM.process = {
    createStyles: function() {
      //Do style processing
      alert("processing styles");
    },
    createClasses = {
      //Do style processing
      alert("processing classes");      
    }
  };
  CPM.process.init = CPM.process.createStyles;
```

Or you can use an external function definition and assign it to both keys:

```
  function createStyles() {
    //Do style processing
    alert("processing styles");
  }
  CPM.process = {
    createStyles: createStyles,
    createClasses = {
      //Do style processing
      alert("processing classes");      
    },
    init: createStyles
  };
```

Comment: @Ianzz Oh right - "init" is a property of the same object :-)

Comment: Yes, the first approach was what I thought of doing but not sure if there are any other hidden gotchas!